# ¿Como hacer consultas ajax desde un archivo js en un widget Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Estoy realizando un widget para wordpress y necesito hacer consultas ajax a un archivo que esta en la misma carpeta. Si solo pongo el nombre del archivo busca en el link donde puse el widget, por ej, si el widget lo coloco en la pagina

```
www.midominio.com/buscador/
```

y el archivo que solicito se llama prueba.php entonces lo que hace es esta solicitud:

```
www.midominio.com/buscador/prueba.php
```

y yo necesito que busque en la misma carpeta (ruta relativa) porque creo que debe ser mas lento con una consulta externa del tipo www.

Lo solucioné provisoriamente con:

```
plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )
```

pero la referencia la quiero hacer desde un archivo js y ademas me parece que no es lo mas optimo. Espero me puedan ayudar y gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1):

La forma CORRECTA de manejar llamadas ajax en Wordpress es esta

#### Archivo php principal de tu plugin

```
<?php //Define los archivos js que se van a encolar. En este caso el archivo que contiene el codigo js para el ajax.
function miplugin_encolar_scripts()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('miplugin-', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'main.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', false);
}

//Ejecuta la funcioon miplugin_encolar_scripts()
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'miplugin_encolar_scripts');

//Estas funciones (HO0Ks) hacen que la funcion prueba_funcion() este disponible cuando se hagan llamas al /admin-ajax.php
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_prueba_funcion', 'prueba_funcion' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_prueba_funcion', 'prueba_funcion' );

function prueba_funcion() {
    //Incluimos el archivo prueba.php que contiene los codigos a ejecutarse durante la peticion
    require_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'prueba.php';
    exit();
}


function miplugin_ajax_enqueue() {
    //Con esta funcion se crea la variable ajaxurl de javascript que es la que usaremos como url para las peticiones del ajax.
    wp_localize_script(
        'miplugin-ajax-script',
        'miplugin',
        array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) )
    );
}

//Con este codigo se ejecuta la funcion miplugin_ajax_enqueue() en el momento correcto
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'miplugin_ajax_enqueue' );
```

En el archivo donde tienes el codigo que hace la llamada ajax (que en mi ejemplo se llama main.js) utiliza como direccion para la peticion `miplugin.ajaxurl` y entre la data enviada agrega un campo llamado `action` y como valor, el nombre de la función que se debe ejecutar (en nuestro caso `prueba_funcion`).

**Ejemplo:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // This does the ajax request
    $.ajax({
        url: miplugin.ajaxurl,
        data: {
            'action': 'prueba_funcion',
            'unadata' : 123456
        },
        success:function(data) {
            // This outputs the result of the ajax request
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(errorThrown){
            console.log(errorThrown);
        }
    });  
              
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, lo que sucede es que yo en esos archivos que encolo hago consultas ajax y mi duda es como señalar al archivo que quiero consultar. Ahora corrijo la pregunta para que se encienta mejor.

Comment: Respuesta actualizada